Generic variable inference in and across mapped types
I'm writing a variadic zip function which takes any number of Iterables and returns a Generator which yields tuples with items from each one, much like Python's zip:
I have the following function:
type IterablesTuple<T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Iterable<infer U> ? U | undefined : never 
};

function* zip1<T extends Iterable<any>[]>(...args: T): Generator<IterablesTuple<T>> {}

Calling it with a few iterables:
const z1 = zip1([1, 2], ['a', 'b'], new Set([true, false]));

I see that the generator z1 returns tuples where each member has the same type as the value produced by the corresponding Iterable's Iterator:
const z1: Generator<[number | undefined, string | undefined, boolean | undefined], any, unknown>

I discovered that the following also works:
type Iterables<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Iterable<T[K]> };
type ZipItem<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | undefined };

function* zip2<T extends any[]>(...args: Iterables<T>): Generator<ZipItem<T>> {}

Calling zip2 with the same iterables, the generator z2 has the same type as z1:
const z2: Generator<[number | undefined, string | undefined, boolean | undefined], any, unknown>

I think zip2's generic variable T is inferred from it's usage in Iterables, and that the inference made in Iterables is shared with ZipItem, but I don't understand the steps that the compiler takes, from inferring T inside Iterable<T>, then T[K] in the mapped type Iterables<T>, then T in zip2<T>, and then finally how this carries over into the mapped type ZipItem<T>.
Can you help me understand the inference steps that the compiler takes for zip2, so that we end up with the same return type in zip2 as in zip1?
Here's a Playground where I have been experimenting with this.

I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you describe more about what you find surprising, and why you are surprised? And isn't [number, string, boolean] correct for a zip function like this? Each iteration would return a tuple with one item from each iterable passed in. So your question appears to be "why don't I get the wrong answer"? But, why you expect the wrong answer is for you tell us.

Your test for ZipItemTest isn't doing the same thing that your call to zip2 does. Presumably you're confused or surprised by inference from mapped types, which used to be documented in the handbook but doesn't seem to be directly anymore. If F<T> is a homomorphic mapped type, then TypeScript can fairly easily infer T from F<T>, which is what's happening in zip2. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer (or find a suitable duplicate target). If not, what's missing?

@AlexWayne I edited the question. Let me know if it's clearer now.

@jcalz I removed the two tests and changed the question to focus on how the type of args influences the return type, in the hope of making it clearer what I'm confused by. I can incorporate the tests into the question again, however, if you think that they provide useful context.

@jcalz Sadly, I can't say that the handbook which you linked to makes it any clearer to me why changing the args type from T to Iterables<T> affects the return type produced by ZipItem<T>. In the example at the end with unproxify, wouldn't the unwrapped member type in the case of the somewhat analogous use of Iterables<T> become the originally wrapped container type, e.g. number[] for the first iterable? But it's as if the unwrapping of Iterables<T> also unwraps each array / set / whatever iterable as well, to produce number, string and boolean?

Hmm, so you still don't understand inference from mapped types. I'm going to try again but I'm not sure I can explain it better. If you call zip2(...a), then the compiler is given the value a of a type it needs to match to Iterables<T>. So it needs to infer T from that. If I told you that the type [number[], string[], Set(boolean)] is assignable to Iterables<T>, what does that imply about T? From the definition of Iterables, you could conclude it has to be [number, string, boolean], right? Does this part make sense?

(See prev comment) ZipItem works the same in your two versions of zip2; T is inferred differently. The difference between <T>(t: T) => G<T> and <T>(ft: F<T>) => G<T> has nothing to do with G. Of course if you call those functions with the same argument you'll get different outputs, but that's because T will be inferred to be different things. In the t case, it's saying "give me something and I'll put it in a box", whereas the ft case says "give me something in a bag and I'll take the thing out of the bag and put it in a box".  The "put it in a box" is the same.

(see prev comment) so how can we proceed here? I'm not sure how to overcome such a fundamental misconception without just repeating myself. Let me know if anything I've said changes things for you, and if so I can flesh it out into a full answer. If not, then, uh... maybe we're just stuck?

So in the case of t, we give it T which is, say, [number[], string[]], and it's put into the ZipItem box which gives [number[] | undefined, string[] | undefined]. In the case of ft, we give it Iterables<T>, and here I'm thinking, I bet incorrectly, that taking each member of T outside the Iterables bag should give back number[] and string[], respectively, because the Iterables bag holds a number[] and a string[], not a number and a string. Is it really the case that Iterable<T[K]> in the Iterables mapped type is Iterable<number> and Iterable<string>?

Yes, that's where you're incorrect, but I can't understand why you're thinking of it this way. Maybe you're confused because [string[], Set<number>] is not identical to [Iterable<string>, Iterable<number>]? But the former is assignable to the latter. What if I called zip2([xIter, yIter]) where xIter is of type Iterable<X> and yIter is of type Iterable<Y>. Would you agree that T should be [X, Y] in that case?

I think I may be starting to understand this so I wrote an argument for what I think happens, step by step. Does it make any sense?
Array<T> implements a [Symbol.iterator]() method that returns a IterableIterator<T> for any T.
Iterable<T> requires that same [Symbol.iterator]() method for any T.
IterableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>, and also requires the same [Symbol.iterator]() method.
Because IterableIterator<T> is a subtype of Iterator<T>, it is assignable to Iterator<T>. (continued)

(continued) Because Array<T>'s [Symbol.iterator]() is assignable to Iterable<T>'s [Symbol.iterator](), Array<T> itself is assignable to Iterable<T>, for any T.
Now, let's consider the type Iterables<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Iterable<T[K]> }, when T in Iterables<T> is an array of child arrays.
Each such child Array<T'>, no matter its own member type T', is assignable to Iterable<T'>.
Then, in Iterables<T>, T[K] is the type T' such that Array<T'> is assignable to Iterable<T'>. (continued)

(continued) For an Array<string>, T[K] in Iterables and T' in Iterable must therefore be string.
Since T[K] was found to be a string in Iterables<T>, it is also known that T[K] in ZipItem<T> is string as well.
The same argument goes for every remaining child array in the array T that is given to Iterables and ZipItem.

Yes, that's essentially what happens. So, uh, how should we proceed with answering the question? At this point we have scads of comments and I'm still not sure what your original misconception was, exactly... I only understand what's actually happening. Is this question likely to help others if it gets an answer? Right now it feels to me like this is a one-off thing that should just be deleted, but maybe there's some common misunderstanding involved we can explore? I just can't tell.

Of course, no one is more biased than the person who just struggled with this, but I think clarifying a few things here may be useful to others. Kind of like how there are no stupid questions in a classroom; someone else is usually asking themselves a similar question.
I think this question of mine could use a better title, and I’ll suggest one, but let me try to establish what I found particularly confusing and which assumptions I made in this situation which I now think were incorrect. (cont).

(cont) Misunderstandings and clarifications:

While Iterable<number[]> is an iterable of number arrays, Iterable<T[K]> where K possibly indexes a number array in T, is quite different. Here T[K] is itself variable which must be inferred in order for that number array in T, ie the number[T] “over there”, to be assignable to Iterable. So T[K] has double duty as both an unknown variable named T[K] but also as a reference into the type in T indexed by K. I only assumed the latter but not the former. (cont)


(cont) 2. Inferences made in one mapped type carry to other mapped types in the same context.  I incorrectly assumed that inference made in a functions argument would be independent from any inference in that function’s return type. Now I suspect that what is established is something about zip2’s generic variable T, so that T’s shape is discovered in the mapped type used by and then this carries over to the mapped type used by the return type. I kind of want to call this an implicit constraint. (cont)

(cont) Better tittle: Generic variable inference in and across mapped types
So yeah, I think me and others would find it quite useful to see a walkthrough of what the compiler does in inferring these generic variables, and how inference bubbles up, as it were, from specific types like Iterable up to Iterables, then up to zip2, and finally “crosses” over to ZipItem. (cont)

(cont) This is a specific situation but it seems like there’s an opportunity to generalize it into a few important principles one ought to keep in mind when thinking about mapped type and nested generic type inference. Kind of like an integration test, but in the context of documenting how a number of pieces work together. (cont)

(cont) If none of the above catches your fancy, I’m also fine with deleting the question, although then I might actually want to take a stab at synthesizing all these comments into an answer myself, to the extent that the steps I outline above are truthful. However, I’m sure the result would be less useful to others than if it’s done by someone who really knows what they’re talking about. In any case, thank you very much for the conversation and your help so far!

Hmm, maybe I'll write up an answer here. The issue is definitely that you didn't understand inference from mapped types, where the compiler can infer T from {[K in keyof T]: F<T[K]>} assuming that it can infer U from F<U>... for each key K, the type of T[K] is inferred from F<T[K]>.  But your misconception, the thing you thought should be happening, still makes zero sense to me. It would be one thing if you said "I don't see how this works at all" instead of "shouldn't T be [number[], string[], Set<boolean>]?", which is, as far as I can tell, a complete red herring (more)

I think I'd be happy answering if you [edit] to remove those red herring parts, the particular misconception which I suspect is unique to you, and at best will only serve to confuse future readers. Otherwise, if you want to keep it as-is and write your own answer, that's fine too. Let me know.

Okay I'll write it up when I get a chance, might be a few hours from now.

Take your time.

I've explained this as well as I could in an answer. Hope it makes sense.

This is known as inference from mapped types, which used to be documented in the TypeScript handbook but doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere obvious anymore.

First, given
type Iterables<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Iterable<T[K]> };
type ZipItem<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] | undefined };

function* zip2<T extends any[]>(...args: Iterables<T>): Generator<ZipItem<T>> { }   

let's ignore inference entirely and see what the generic type argument T has to be specified with for the following to work:
const z2 = zip2([1, 2], ['a', 'b'], new Set([true, false]));

In order for that to compiler without error, the value [[1, 2], ['a', 'b'], new Set([true, false])] of tuple type [number[], string[], Set<boolean>] must be assignable to the rest parameter of zip2, which is Iterables<T>. Our job is then to try to describe what T has to be for that to be true.
Note that Iterables<T> is a so-called homomorphic mapped type (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean? ) of the form { [K in keyof T]: ⋯T[K]⋯ }.  And homomorphic mapped types map arrays to arrays and tuples to tuples. So since we want a three element tuple to come out of Iterables<T>, we should plug a three-element tuple into Iterables<T> as T.
So T looks like [?, ?, ?]. Let's look at each numeric-like index K in turn to see what has to happen to the corresponding property.  When K="0", the input type is T[0] and the output type is Iterable<T[0]> to which number[] needs to be assignable.  The best choice for T[0] would therefore be number, since number[] is assignable to Iterable<number>.  For K="1" the input type T[1] should be string for the same reason. And for K="2", we need a type T[K] such that Set<boolean> is assignable to Iterable<T[K]>.  Looks like we want boolean for that.  So that means T should be [number, string, boolean].
Let's test that out by calling zip2 with T manually specified as [number, string, boolean]:
const z2 = zip2<[number, string, boolean]>(
  [1, 2], ['a', 'b'], new Set([true, false])
); // okay

That compiles without error, so our choice for T is at least compatible with our input arguments.  From there, you can determine that the type of z2 will be Generator<ZipItem<[number, string, boolean]>>, which is Generator<[number | undefined, string | undefined, boolean | undefined]>.

That's how we'd have to proceed if inference didn't exist or didn't work the way we wanted.  But luckily for us, you can just call zip2() with the same arguments, without manually specifying T as [number, string, boolean], and yet, automagically, T is inferred to be [number, string, boolean] all the same:
const z2 = zip2([1, 2], ['a', 'b'], new Set([true, false]));
/* function zip2<[number, string, boolean]>(
      args_0: Iterable<number>, 
      args_1: Iterable<string>, 
      args_2: Iterable<boolean>
): Generator<[number | undefined, string | undefined, boolean | undefined]> */

How does this happen?
Well, as said above, it's inference from (homomorphic) mapped types.  When you have a homomorphic mapped type of the form { [K in keyof T]: F<T[K]> }, the compiler will be able to infer T from that type, as long as it can infer X from F<X>.  For each property key K of { [K in keyof T]: F<T[K]> }, the compiler will infer T[K] from F<T[K]>, and use it to build up T.  This is a fairly powerful bit of inference that enables your code to work.
It means, as long as TypeScript can infer T from Iterable<T>, then it can infer T from Iterables<T> as well.  And it performs the inference similarly to the way I described the manual process above:

It sees that Iterables<T> is a three-element tuple, and therefore T will be  three-element tuple.
For K="0", it sees that Iterables<T>[0], which is Iterable<T[0]>, matches number[]. Since number[] is assignable to Iterable<number>, then T[0] should be number.
For K="1", it sees that Iterables<T>[1], which is Iterable<T[1]>, matches string[]. Since string[] is assignable to Iterable<string>, then T[1] should be string.
For K="2", it sees that Iterables<T>[2], which is Iterable<T[2]>, matches Set<boolean>. Since Set<boolean> is assignable to Iterable<boolean>, then T[2] should be boolean.
Therefore T is [number, string, boolean].

And again, once T is inferred as [number, string, boolean], the output type Generator<ZipItem<T>> is Generator<ZipItem<[number, string, boolean]>> which is Generator<[number | undefined, string | undefined, boolean | undefined]>.
Playground link to code
